# d3.js Color Groups for Radar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, radar-chart

I'm using this [d3 Radar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/21746a9668ffdf6d8242), and now I want to color the groups.

Here's my data -

```
var data = [
  [
     {axis:"volume(N)",value:0.074095419,group:"one"},
     {axis:"heightBBOX(N)",value:0.618900916,group:"one"},
     {axis:"floor_area(N)",value:0.239036487,group:"one"},
     {axis:"RatioSunExp_TotWall",value:0.670908597,group:"one"
  }],
  [
     {axis:"volume(N)",value:0.373966243,group:"two"},
     {axis:"heightBBOX(N)",value:0.418068276,group:"two"},
     {axis:"floor_area(N)",value:0.039064467,group:"two"},
     {axis:"RatioSunExp_TotWall",value:0.341108011,group:"two"
  }],
  [
     {axis:"volume(N)",value:0.675991163,group:"two"},
     {axis:"heightBBOX(N)",value:0.815015265,group:"two"},
     {axis:"floor_area(N)",value:0.94061374,group:"two"},
     {axis:"RatioSunExp_TotWall",value:0.974062924,group:"two"
  }],
  [
     {axis:"volume(N)",value:0.875950233,group:"two"},
     {axis:"heightBBOX(N)",value:0.210852068,group:"two"},
     {axis:"floor_area(N)",value:0.540645865,group:"two"},
     {axis:"RatioSunExp_TotWall",value:0.074841546,group:"two"
  }]]
```

and these are my color options

```
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["one","two"])
        .range(["#CC333F","#53e87d"]);
```

I want to color the group *one* with a specific color and the group *two* with another color. How can i do?

**update:** when I use the code below, all the charts are yellow. So I know that the group is undefined. How can I fix this ?

```
color: function(d){
    if(d.group == "one"){
        return "red";
        }
    if(d.group == "two"){
        return "green";
        }
    else{
        return "yellow";
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you show us a working full code ?

Comment: @Temani-afif here is a working [full code](https://jsfiddle.net/c3wu7ftr/1/)

Comment: the second way you commented works well ... the actual one is not good : https://jsfiddle.net/c3wu7ftr/2/

Comment: @Temani-afif but this is not what i want. i need to colorize group "one" with one color (ex. red) and group "two" with another color (ex. green). in this code 3 of the dataset's (group "two") must be green and one dataset (group "one") must be red.

Comment: ok got it, let me check then

Comment: hope my explanation is clear ;)

Comment: and what about my solution ? :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif first of all thank you very much. your answer worked, but your variant gets critical when I use e. g. 2000 datasets. (I didn't write it here, so you didn't include it of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that in `radarChartOptions` this...

```
color: function(d){
```

... doesn't retrieve the `datum` bound to each element.

The best solution here is looking at the plugin, or emailing its author, to find out how he/she is passing the options. As I don't have time to check the plugin documentation, here is a simple solution, which paints the paths/circles **after** they are rendered:

```
d3.selectAll(".radarArea").each(function(d){
  d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d[0].group))
});

d3.selectAll(".radarStroke").each(function(d){
  d3.select(this).style("stroke", color(d[0].group))
});

d3.selectAll(".radarCircle").each(function(d){
  d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.group))
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1j59znu9/

Comment: i guess the main issue is that the OP is changing the structure of the Data and the plugin seems to be designed for a specfic structure so there is no way to get the *group* element he added to the structure. So i guess he need to re-think about another way then changing the data structure

Comment: Yes, that's the issue, as I explain in the answer. However, OP can simply manipulate the DOM, as I'm doing here: the data is bound to the element. Therefore, it's easily accessible.